# How can I override the default error path in Identity Server 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an Identity Server 4 implementation where I'm migrating the UI from ASP.NET MVC to a decoupled React app. The problem I have is that when Identity Server handles an error (such as an invalid client) it redirects to `/home/error?errorId=<error-id>` using, I assume, the path [defined in a constant here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Constants.cs). I would like to customise this error path so it matches a route in my React app. Any idea how to do this? The nearest I've found to an answer is [here on Github](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/54) where the OP asks if there are plans to make these constants customisable, and Brock Allen replies "Yep"! That was 2016

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an overload of `AddIdentityServer` that you can use to configure the [`IdentityServerOptions`](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/options.html) that gets used by IdentityServer. Here's an example that sets the [`ErrorUrl`](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/options.html#userinteraction) property:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.UserInteraction.ErrorUrl = "/path/to/error";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an older question. But I use ASP.NET Core 3.1 and I have enabled DeveloperExceptionPage:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
```

And I would like to let any errors be handled there as well. Is there a way to deserialize the ***errorId*** parameter so the error can be parsed and thrown with details for **Development** purpose?

Comment: I'd ask this as a new question if I were you. I know Identity Server has its own internal logging which I'm sure will include these error details. In the past I've hooked this up to Application Insights which when debugging with Visual Studio hold the logs in memory for review.